# XML Elements positional Processing with XSLT.

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have this sample xml.

```
    <I>
<!-- SL REPEATS * TIMES -->
    <SL>
<!-- SE REPEATS * TIMES -->
        <SE></SE>
        <SE></SE>
        <SE></SE>
    </SL>
    <SL>
        <SE></SE>        
        <SE></SE>
    </SL>
    <SL>
        <SE></SE>
        <SE></SE>
        <SE></SE>
    </SL>
    <SL>        
        <SE></SE>
    </SL>
</I>



I want to generate sequential id numbers for <SE> starting with first one. Resultant needs to be like this.

    <I>
<!-- SL REPEATS * TIMES -->
    <SL>
<!-- SE REPEATS * TIMES -->
        <SE id="1"></SE>
        <SE id="2"></SE>
        <SE id="3"></SE>
    </SL>
    <SL>
        <SE id="4"></SE>        
        <SE id="5"></SE>
    </SL>
    <SL>
        <SE id="6"></SE>
        <SE id="7"></SE>
        <SE id="8"></SE>
    </SL>
    <SL>        
        <SE id="9"></SE>
    </SL>
</I>
```

I tried using count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) + 1" on a template that matches . But it restarts numbers after every SL.

Thanks for checking. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xsl:number level="any"/>` in a template

```
<xsl:template match="SE">
  <SE>
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:number level="any"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </SE>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course you need [the identity transformation template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) as well to copy the other nodes.

If there can be `SE` outside of `I` you don't want to count then use `<xsl:number level="any" from="I"/>`.